# How can I extend draggable area of jQuery draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Trying to enhance usability of a jQuery draggable I run into following issue. I have a div container, containing an (small) image and a text, giving the user the oportunity to drag the image into an text editor.

If I add the .draggable to the img everything works fine, but since the image is quite small usability is not good.

So, what I want to do is making the div container draggable, but only drag the img. Do anyone knows a solution?

EDIT: here is the code

```
HTML += '<div id="row'+file.id+'" class="box downloadfilerow" style="opacity: 1;height:'+(that.options.previewMaxHeight)+'px;overflow-y:auto;padding:8px 0px 8px 2px;border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;">';
if (file.preview_url) {
   if (<?=json_encode($uploadAllowed)?>) {
        HTML +='<div class="delete">';
        HTML +='<button class="btn" style="float:right;margin:'+(that.options.previewMaxHeight/8)+'px;" id="del'+file.id+'" title="<?=Yii::t('widgets/FileSelector', 'Delete')?>" rel="tooltip">';
        HTML +='<i class="icon-trash"></i>';
        HTML +='</button>';
        //HTML +='<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" style="float:left;margin:0px 10px;height:'+that.options.previewMaxHeight+'px;">';
        HTML +='</div>';
    }
    HTML +='<div style="float:left;height:'+that.options.previewMaxHeight+'px"><img data-view-url="'+file.view_url+'" style="float:left;cursor:move;max-width:'+that.options.previewMaxWidth+'px;max-height:'+that.options.previewMaxHeight+'px;" data-file="'+file.id+'" data-filename="'+file.name+'" id="'+file.id+'" src="'+ file.preview_url +'"></div>';
    HTML += namedLink;
    HTML += fileSize;
```

and

```
$("#row"+file.id).draggable({ helper: 'clone', zIndex: 2700, appendTo: 'body'});
```

Comment: So you want to drag the entire container and on drop drop only the contained image? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/fGtzA/

Comment: can you show us the code you're working with?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward i only want to drag the image. but if the user for example clicks 30px beside the image the function should "tolerate" this and let him drag the image